# getDirty() not pickup added leading zero

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model `Product` that contains a column `productcode`. This is a varchar/string in the MySQL database.

Suppose I have a product in the database with as `product code`: `1000`.

Then when I perform the following action:

```php
$product->fill(['productcode' => '01000']);
```

And then the `$product->getDirty()` query, `productcode` does not appear in the array.

I assume this is due to a loose check `==` instead of strict `===`.

For now, I first adjust the code with a dummy code and then enter the correct code (01000)

Has anyone else experienced this problem and maybe found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this weird behaviour myself as well. Basically, it's a part of laravel's 'functionality'. When performing the `save()` method on an eloquent model, laravel first checks which fields are considered dirty and only updates those. The equality of the old and new value is check by `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes::originalIsEquivalent`, which ends with following code:

```php
return is_numeric($attribute) && is_numeric($original)
            && BigDecimal::of($attribute)->isEqualTo($original);
```

Since the numeric values for both productcode values are equal according to those lines, they are not considered dirty and as such are not updated.

You can simply cast your property to be a string to avoid this behaviour:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = ['productcode' => 'string'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `fill()` to work you need to have the `productcode` field placed in the fillables array in the `Product` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'productcode'
];
```

The fill method uses this information to know whether it can be filled in or not:

```
// Fragment of the fill method on the model
if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
    $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vitor, the structure of the model is correctly defined with fillables etc. As I mentioned, trying with another value, like 'code-abc' will work fine.

Comment: By chance you don't have a cast to int?

Comment: Hi Vitor,  No, that isn't the case. When updating `code-a` to `code-b` there isn't any problem. It really seems to be the loose check within the `getDirty()` method.